# Formatear resultados de una consulta MySQL en JSON anidando resultados de una sub query

Tags: mysql, json, nodejs

Estoy llamando a una tabla desde nodeJS y obtengo el resultado de la tabla correctamente

```
            export function listProductos(req: Request, res: Response) {
                //const id_producto = MySQL.instance.conn.escape(req.params.id_producto);
                const objeto = "";
                const query = `SELECT a.nombre_producto,b.id_imagen_producto,b.id_imagen_producto  FROM ymvdc_producto a
            INNER JOIN ymvdc_imagenes_producto b ON a.id_producto = b.id_producto)`;
            
                MySQL.ejecutarQuery(query, objeto, (error: any, productos: Productos[]) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    warning: "error",
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json({
                    ok: true,
                    productos: productos,
                    });
                }
                });
            }
```

Sin embargo, necesito que la salida JSON en res.json sea del tipo:

```
            {
                "ok": true,
                "productos": [{
                        "nombre_producto": "Producto concreto",
                        "imagenes": [{
                            "id_imagen_producto": "1",
                            "imagen_producto": "imagen 1"
                        }, {
                            "id_imagen_producto": "2",
                            "imagen_producto": "imagen 2"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "nombre_producto": "Producto concreto 2",
                        "imagenes": [{
                            "id_imagen_producto": "1",
                            "imagen_producto": "imagen 1"
                        }, {
                            "id_imagen_producto": "2",
                            "imagen_producto": "imagen 2"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Cómo debería darle la salida? Alguna sugerencia?

EDITO: adjunto la interface

```
export interface Productos {
  id_producto?: string;
  id_usuario: string;
  nombre_producto: string;
  descripcion_producto: string;
  id_categoria: string;
  id_subcategoria: string;

  id_imagen_producto: [];
  imagen_producto: [];
}
```

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido. La sentencia SQL te da como resultado (n) filas con un nombre de producto y dos id_imagen_producto (que son las mismas) y no son un arreglo como está definido en el interface. ¿ Y donde consigues la imagen_producto? De todos modos, para formatear la salida en la respuesta, puedes usar un productos.forEach y crear otro arreglo de objetos formateados según tus necesidades.

Comment: @VicenteSanchez de hecho por eso lanzo la cuestión, para darle sentido. La imagen_producto la extraigo de la tabla ymvdc_imagenes_producto, cada fila es una imagen asociada a un id_producto. Entiendo lo que me comentas, sin embargo no sé cómo darle salida en el res.json para conseguir el array multidimensional. La idea la veo, sin embargo no tengo clara la sintaxis.

Comment: y si usas alias en las consultas, de esta forma les podrías poner los nombres de la interface

Comment: aunque si es verdad que esto se hace fácil en angular `http.post<Productos>` tocaria traducir este metodo a js

Comment: @VicenteSanchez correcto, sin embargo necesito las imágenes dela tabla imágenes relacionadas con cada id del producto de la tabla de productos. Lo estoy llamando con un INNER JOIN pero no sé si es la solución

Comment: Tienes que tener claro que una consulta SQL te da como resultado una tabla, esto es, filas y columnas... y tu, en el callback declaras el tipo como un array de Productos, pero en el interface de tienes otros dos array que son id_imagen_producto e imagen_producto... voy a ver si te lo puedo desarrollar mejor...

Comment: Por otro lado, si usas un INNER JOIN, se dará el caso, de que si tienes algun producto que no tiene imagen, no estará en la lista... Usa un LEFT JOIN, para asegurarte que tienes TODOS los productos, independientemente de si tienen imagenes o no...

Answer (score 8):

Desde el principio... Supongo que tienes las tablas de la siguiente forma:

ymvdc_producto

```
| id_producto | nombre_producto | 
| ----------: | --------------- | 
| 1           | Manzana         | 
| 2           | Limón           | 
| 3           | Naranja         | 
| 4           | Tomate          |
```

ymvdc_imagenes_producto

```
| id_imagen_producto | id_producto | imagen_producto             | 
| -----------------: | ----------: | --------------------------- | 
| 1                  | 1           | imagen_manzana1.jpg         | 
| 3                  | 2           | imagen_limón.jpg            | 
| 5                  | 3           | imagen_naranja_murcia.jpg   | 
| 7                  | 3           | imagen_naranja_valencia.jpg | 
| 9                  | 1           | imagen_manzana2.jpg         |
```

Con una consulta del tipo:

```
SELECT a.nombre_producto,b.id_imagen_producto,b.imagen_producto
FROM ymvdc_producto a
LEFT JOIN ymvdc_imagenes_producto b ON a.id_producto = b.id_producto
ORDER BY nombre_producto
```

Resultará una tabla más o menos así:

```
| nombre_producto | id_imagen_producto | imagen_producto             | 
| --------------- | -----------------: | --------------------------- | 
| Limón           | 3                  | imagen_limón.jpg            | 
| Manzana         | 9                  | imagen_manzana2.jpg         | 
| Manzana         | 1                  | imagen_manzana1.jpg         | 
| Naranja         | 5                  | imagen_naranja_murcia.jpg   | 
| Naranja         | 7                  | imagen_naranja_valencia.jpg | 
| Tomate          |                    |                             |
```

Como verás, el resultado es una tabla que repite el producto tantas veces como imagenes tiene asignadas. Tomate no tiene ninguna, pero se incluye por usar *LEFT* en vez de *INNER*, manzana y naranja tiene dos imagenes por cada producto y limón solo tiene una imagen.

Para que estos datos, sean enviados como quieres, tienes que organizarlos tu mismo.

```
export function listProductos(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const objeto = '';
    const query =
        `SELECT a.nombre_producto,b.id_imagen_producto,b.imagen_producto ` +
        `FROM ymvdc_producto a LEFT JOIN ymvdc_imagenes_producto b ON a.id_producto = b.id_producto ` +
        `ORDER BY nombre_producto;`;

    MySQL.ejecutarQuery(query, objeto, (error: any, datos: any[]) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                warning: 'error',
            });
        } else {
            // Creamos una lista de productos sin duplicados []

            let productosUnicos: string[] = [];

            datos.forEach((row: any) => {
                if (!productosUnicos.includes(row.nombre_producto)) {
                    productosUnicos.push(row.nombre_producto);
                }
            });

            // Ahora vamos a buscar las imagenes de cada producto y
            // creamos los objetos que responderemos

            let resultado: any[] = [];

            productosUnicos.forEach((producto: string) => {
                // Creamos un objeto temporal que contendrá el nombre del producto
                // y un array de las imagenes que le correspondan (inicialmente vacio)

                let objTemporal: any = {
                    nombre_producto: producto,
                    imagenes: [],
                };

                datos.forEach((row: any) => {
                    if (String(row.nombre_producto) === producto) {
                        // Buscamos las imagenes del producto y las incluimos en
                        // el objeto temporal, dentro del array de imagenes
                        objTemporal.imagenes.push({
                            id_imagen_producto: row.id_imagen_producto,
                            imagen_producto: row.imagen_producto,
                        });
                    }
                });

                // Incorporamos el objeto temporal del producto y sus imagenes
                // en el array resultado y asi como tantos productos unicos...
                resultado.push(objTemporal);
            });

            res.json({
                ok: true,
                productos: resultado,
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Como puedes ver en el código (no probado) lo que hacemos es 'construir' objetos de los productos con sus imagenes y añadirlas al resultado final. Hay formas más directas de hacerlo pero también más dificil de entender...

El resultado sería lo que buscabas, eso creo...

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "productos": [
        {
            "nombre_producto": "Manzana",
            "imagenes": [
                {
                    "id_imagen_producto": "1",
                    "imagen_producto": "imagen_manzana1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "id_imagen_producto": "9",
                    "imagen_producto": "imagen_manzana2.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "nombre_producto": "Limón",
            "imagenes": [
                {
                    "id_imagen_producto": "3",
                    "imagen_producto": "imagen_limón.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "nombre_producto": "Naranja",
            "imagenes": [
                {
                    "id_imagen_producto": "5",
                    "imagen_producto": "imagen_naranja_murciajpg"
                },
                {
                    "id_imagen_producto": "7",
                    "imagen_producto": "imagen_naranja_valencia.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "nombre_producto": "Tomate",
            "imagenes": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Comment: genial, brillante. Funciona. Respuesta válida. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si deseo añadir más tablas con LEFT JOIN se me duplican las imágenes por cada una, cómo lo evito? y cómo puedo añadir el id_producto además del nombre? realmente es útil, pero si hay dos productos con el mismo nombre pierdo uno. Habría manera de diferenciarlos por id_producto? es un campo común entre las tablas productos e imágenes

Comment: Este solución resolvió el problema que tenías, recomiendo marcar como válida y entregar recompensa. Tu problema con la duplicidad de imágenes puedes resolverla en otro hilo, puesto que es un escenario distinto al problema planteado.